# PlayerPrefs not saving correctly any fixes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to save an score into the player prefs but it stays at 0 for some weird reason.
I have no clue why it stays at 0 since i putted the score variable into the int correctly i think.

```
public void SaveButtonClick(){
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", score_system.score);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score"));
}
```

```
public void start()
{
score_system.score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
}
```

I expected to have the score saved into the playerprefs normally but it doesn't and always goes to 0 from what i tested

Comment: Can you also print score_system.score after you call SetInt(), just to be absolutely sure that it's not actually zero? Because it should be working fine from what I can tell.

Comment: Looks like a **Typo**: `start` != `Start` so Unity doesn't find it and your object is never initialized

Answer (score 1):

Your method:

```cs
public void start()
{
    score_system.score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
}
```

… should be:

```cs
public void Start()
{
    score_system.score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
}
```

Note that capital ‘S’ for `Start`.